# Why do I have to refresh before embedded YouTube video will show?

Tags: files, nodes

I just uploaded a YouTube video using the embed code. Each time I visit it, the video will only show on the second page load (when the page is refreshed). This is on a Drupal 7 site using AdaptiveTheme as the base theme with very minor CSS changes.

I'm half just posting here so that no one else spends 45 minutes banging their head against input filters before realizing the problem isn't there. But if anyone knows why this is the case, I would love an explanation.

Comment: I assume you already verified this with multiple browsers/OS's :)